# Sliding div not moving smoothly

Tags: javascript

I have a slider which im trying to slide by using mouse move but it doesn't move naturally it jumps in stages but i do not know why.

I have a jsfiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/97Mnf/3/ you will see the slider doesn't move with the mouse properly.

My code is :

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('cursor').addEventListener("mousedown", mousePos, false);   
}

function mousePos(e){   
    var x = e.pageX;
    document.getElementById('cursor').addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){mousemoveCalc(e,x);}, false);
    document.getElementById('cursor').removeEventListener("mouseup", mousemoveCalc, false); //not working
    document.getElementById('cursor').removeEventListener("mouseout", mousemoveCalc, false); //not working
}   

function mousemoveCalc(e,x){    
    var difx = 0 + parseInt(x + e.pageX);

            if(difx > 270){
                 difx=270;
            }else if(difx<0){
                 difx=0;
            }

    document.getElementById('cursor').style.left = difx+'px';

}
```

Comment: You never actually set any `mouseup` or `mouseout` events, so how exactly do you expect removing them to work?

Comment: oh my bad. that solves the first part. what about the movement of the slider in the fiddle?

Comment: You are adding multiple event listeners by executing `mousePos` every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `var difx = e.pageX-x;` instead of `x+e.pageX`. Also, you may want to attach your `mousemove` event to the document itself so you aren't required to keep the mouse on the slider while dragging it. Finally, your `mouseup` logic is all wrong. You need to add an event listener that, when fired, removes all handlers